# Scroll background image proportionate to overall location in a page

Tags: html, background, scroll, location, masking

I've been exploring methods for full-width background images combined with type. I found this website: http://starvedforattention.org/

I cannot figure out the logic for how the page works once the user starts scrolling. I know it's along the lines of big DIVs with backgrounds alongside setting absolute/relative locations.

Approaches for coding this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, what you are looking for is a [Parallax Scrolling Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling).

Perhaps you must take a look to [jParallax](http://stephband.info/jparallax/) if you're going to work with [jQuery](http://jquery.com). :)

Best!